# How do I use ScaleX and RenderTransform on a text block whilst keeping horizontal alignment?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am trying to create a popup which based on some data the user enters will generate a preview of something which will be printed out.

One of the options is to stretch the text to double its usual width so I have used the ScaleTransform option of the textblock. This works but I am having some issues with the alignment, when I set the Horizontal alignment to Left the stretched text displays with half of the text cut off. Central alignment is mostly ok, the text isn't perfectly central though.

Is there any way I can make this text stretch whilst still maintaining the alignment?

```
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding CouponLine}" 
                 FontWeight="{Binding FontWeight}"
                 HorizontalAlignment="{Binding Alignment}"
                 FontSize="{Binding FontSize}"
                 RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
             <TextBlock.RenderTransform>
                     <ScaleTransform ScaleX="{Binding ScaleX}" ScaleY="1" CenterX=".5"/>
              </TextBlock.RenderTransform>
       </TextBlock>
   </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that RenderTransform ignores the boundaries of the element containing it, whereas using LayoutTransform will keep the transformed text within the boundaries of its parent element.

```
<TextBlock.LayoutTransform>
   <ScaleTransform ScaleX="{Binding ScaleX}" ScaleY="1" CenterX=".5"/>
</TextBlock.LayoutTransform>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try TextAlignment="Center" instead of HorizontalAlignment

Comment: No luck unfortunately, it seemed to make the text actually move further to the left outside of the control